# Inverse of a tridiagonal, irreducible, weakly diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following matrix:

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -\frac{k-1}{k} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
-\frac{2}{k} & 1 & -\frac{k-2}{k} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & -\frac{3}{k} & 1 & -\frac{k-3}{k}  & 0 & 0& \cdots\\
0 & 0 & -\frac{4}{k} & 1 & -\frac{k-4}{k}  & 0 & \cdots\\
\cdots& \cdots& \cdots& \cdots& \cdots& \cdots& \cdots\end{array} \right)$

Since it is  tridiagonal, irreducible, weakly diagonally dominant matrix, I know it is invertible. Is there any easy way to find the inverse in terms of the parameters?

Comment: you can find how to find the inverse of a tridiagonal matrix here:
http://www.mat.uc.pt/preprints/ps/p0516.pdf